# Is there a chance to insert div class into javascript through css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am in a situation that is above my knowledge of programming. So I have a gallery with Prettyphoto lightbox there is prettyphoto.js file implemented in the theme so it's not editable through plugin section. Lightbox have navigation class, but I want to add one more button into it.

[image: Navigation panel and div class]

All this is inside a JavaScript file, but I didn't find way to edit it.
Also I already have code for button that I used inside another php file with the same purpose. It looks like this:

```
<div class="sbfb" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 15px">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                               <img src="http://flyvideoproduction.com/newpageWP/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-e1486941744317.png" padding="-50px">
                      </a>
                        </div>
```

So is there a chance to put this code inside that div pp_nav class? And show it left to the navigation?

Comment: You need to improve your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem for javascript / jquery.

The biggest issue here is the markup for the pp_nav is location in the js library.  Take a closer look here at line 57:

> https://github.com/scaron/prettyphoto/blob/master/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js

So there is no easy way to use the php function **get_permalink()** provided by WordPress because the code that generates the pp_nav is called on the client side after the initial page load.

My suggestion would be find what event is firing the creation of the Pretty Photo popup (i.e. when the user clicks on the photo maybe?)

Then bind a function to the event as such:

```
$( ".zoom-image" ).bind( "click", function() {
  addSocialLinksToPPNav();
});
```

And the function addSocialLinksToPPNav() would look something like:

```
function addSocialLinksToPPNav()
{
    $('.pp_nav').each(function()
    {
        var html = '<div class="sbfb" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 15px"><a href="generate-your-link-in-js"></a></div>';
        $(this).append(html);
    })
}
```

But this assumes you can generate the same link as **get_permalink** produces via javascript.

This is my general understanding of your problem.  Its hard to understand the full depth of your problem without knowing the full markup of your page.